# Using meta refresh tag in the iframe source page causes the page to refresh where iframe has being called

Tags: html, iframe, metadata

I was finding a quick way for a simple chat page, as I don't want to use Ajax or jQuery so I used the below tag on the source page like for example `page2.php`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
<!--And the page content goes here-->
```

And I used this on `page1.php`

```
<iframe src="page2.php" border="1"></iframe>
```

Now what I expected was only `iframe` to be refreshed but the the whole `page1.php` is refreshed, why that so? Than what's the use of declaring `meta refresh` on `page2.php`? Does actually using `iframe` embeds the markup of the source page in the page where we are using the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like because of the way the iframe is loaded there is no way around this issue. The iframe must be loaded into the DOM in order for it to work, and once it has been it appears the meta refresh is affecting the page as a whole.

Instead, you can use the following onLoad [or, if you're using jQuery in $(document).ready()]:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
                        window.frames['someLogicalName'].location.reload();
            },2000);
```

And then adjust your iframe:

```
<iframe src="page2.php" name="someLogicalName" border="1"></iframe>
```